# segmentation fault memory dumped

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure

I have following code. I got a error that 'segmentation fault memory dumped' when I write an array 'ADDRESS.Person' to any value. any one please help me to solve a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char Person[15];
} stName;

typedef struct
{
    stName      Name;
} stSociety;

stSociety* SOCIETY;

#define ADDRESS    SOCIETY->Name


int main()
{

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
        ADDRESS.Person[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("ADDRESS.Person=%s\n", ADDRESS.Person);

    printf("Finished");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `SOCIETY` is pointing? You need to make it to point to valid memory before dereferencing .

Comment: `Person` is a `char[15]` yet you write from `0` to `31`? Also you never allocate `SOCIETY` or point to an object which has been allocated.

Comment: BTW:  `#define ADDRESS SOCIETY->Name` is a very bad idea, it only adds confusion to your code. And all capital identifiers should only be used for macros, this is by convention.

Comment: Also tell us what you're trying to achieve, then we can help you into the right direction. What is your code supposed to print?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have just declared the structs , you need to create them as well and hence,SOCIETY is pointing to nothing.Also you are iterating through 32 values whereas there are only 15 in the char array.I have modifed the code ,hopefully you will get an idea here

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char Person[15];
} stName;

typedef struct
{
    stName      Name;
} stSociety;

#define ADDRESS    SOCIETY->Name


int main()
{

stSociety* SOCIETY,sample;
SOCIETY = &sample;


    int i;

    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
       ADDRESS.Person[i] = '0';

    }

    printf("ADDRESS.Person=%s\n", ADDRESS.Person);

    printf("Finished");
    return 0;
}
```